# can netbeans learn php custom function arguments of class?

Tags: php, netbeans

I have:

```
class myClass {
  function test($arg1,$arg2) {
    echo $arg1 & $arg2;
  }
}

$m = new myClass();
//can I use any kind of annotation to get argument-list of
$m->test(|
```

//ADD//

I guess Netbeans doesn't natively understand that m = myClass, so something like

```
$m = newClass();
/* @ var m = class newClass */
/* now nb can list the args when typing.. */
$m->test(
```

regards

Comment: Do you mean for netbeans to "know" the arguments for auto-complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found [ctrl] + [space] down the road, at

```
$m->test|
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want notes for each of the arguments, use phpdoc commenting (which NetBeans completes for you automagiaclly):

Just type

```
/**
```

on the line above your function definition and hit the `enter` key. NetBeans will automatically write your phpdoc comments in the space above your function. If you have a `return` in your function, phpdoc will be written for that as well:

```
/**
 *
 * @param type $arg1
 * @param type $arg2
 * @return type
 */
function myFunc($arg1, $arg2) {
    $test = "";
    return $test;
}
```

Then you just replace `type` with the data type of the parameter, and add notes after the parameter name.

Comment: please see added info, (the question is not related to phpdoc).

Comment: @user247245 Update NetBeans. It should do this automatically. As long as you explicitly assign the `new myClass()` to `$m`, NetBeans will know which auto-complete to pull up. Or you can hit `ctrl + p` (in NetBeans, that's not print - it's *show parameters*, for some reason).